# Program run under cron creates file in wrong path

Tags: perl, cron

I am trying to execute a Perl script using crontab.

Manually, the script works fine, but when I use cron, I get an error

> /home/dev/test.csv : not readable

`/home/dev/test.csv` is a file generated by the script, but it is created as `/home/test.csv` and
I don't know how or why.

This is my crontab:

```
/3 * * * * /home/dev/metrique.pl &> /home/dev/output.txt
```

---

this is my code :

```
#!/sw/freetools/perl/5.8.8/Linux/rh50/x86_64/bin/perl

#use strict ;
#use warnings ;
use DBI ;
use DateTime ;
use Text::CSV;
use MIME::Lite;

my $Month = DateTime->now->subtract(months=>0)->truncate(to=>'month') ->strftime('%B') ; 
my $Date = DateTime->now->subtract(months=>0)->truncate(to=>'month') ->strftime('%Y-%m') ;
$Date ="%".$Date."%" ;
my %info = (db =>  "ilico", host => "gnx5910.gnb.st.com", user => "ilicousr", pass => "" );
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$info{db};$info{host}", $info{user}, $info{pass});
my @record ;        
my %Report;
my @other;
my @region = qw{EMEA AME ASIA INDIA Global-WAN}; 
my @scope = qw{wan lan specific};
my $total_weekly = 0;
my $total_usage = 0;
my $weekly = '2';
my $usage = '1';
my @top_user ;
my @array ;
my @user ;
my %hash = ();
my %sum = ();
my %LOGIN_W = ();
my %Groupe = ();
my %hash1 = ();
my %Nom_Complet = ();
my %NUMBER = ();

my $filename1="NBgenerated_Reports.csv";
my $filename2="Report_Scope.csv";
my $filename3 ="Top_10_Features.csv";
my $filename4 ="Top_10_Users.csv";
my $filename5 ="/sw/st/itcad/setup/shared_data/ldp_om.csv";
my $filename6 ="Report_Groupe.csv";

open(my $fh1, ">", $filename1) or die "cannot open < $filename1: $!";
open(my $fh2, ">", $filename2) or die "cannot open < $filename2: $!";
open(my $fh3, ">", $filename3) or die "cannot open < $filename3: $!";
open(my $fh4, ">", $filename4) or die "cannot open < $filename4: $!";
open(my $fh5, "<", $filename5) or die "cannot open < $filename5: $!";
open(my $fh6, ">", $filename6) or die "cannot open < $filename6: $!";

print $fh1 "Region; Usage_Report; Weekly; \n";
print $fh2 "Scope; NB; \n";
print $fh3 "Feature; NB; \n";
print $fh4 "User; NB_Report ;Groupe \n";
print $fh6 "Groupe; NB_Report \n";


#usage & weekly
my $sql  = qq/SELECT COUNT( `Region`.`RegID` ) FROM `iLico_Log`, `Region` WHERE `iLico_Log`.`Date` LIKE ? AND `Region`.`RegID` = `iLico_Log`.`RegID` AND `iLico_Log`.`Type` = ? 
        AND `Region`.`RegName` LIKE ? / ; 

foreach my $reg (@region){ 
 foreach my $type ($weekly, $usage){  
  my $sth  = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die ("unable to prepare");
     $sth->execute(($Date, $type, $reg)) ;
    @record = $sth -> fetchrow_array();
        $Report{$reg}{$type}=$record[0]; 
    }
}

foreach my $reg (keys %Report) {
    $total_usage += $_ for($Report{$reg}{$usage});
    $total_weekly += $_ for($Report{$reg}{$weekly});
    print $fh1 "$reg ; $Report{$reg}{$usage}; $Report{$reg}{$weekly} \n"; 
    }

    print $fh1 "total; $total_usage; $total_weekly; \n";

#scope
my $SCOPE = qq/SELECT COUNT(logID ) FROM `iLico_Log` WHERE `iLico_Log`.`Date` LIKE ? AND `iLico_Log`.`scope`= ?/;
foreach my $sc (@scope){
    my $sth  = $dbh->prepare($SCOPE) or die ("unable to prepare");
         $sth->execute($Date, $sc) ; 
        my @record = $sth -> fetchrow_array();
     print $fh2 "$sc; @record; \n";
     }

#Top 10 features
my $TopFeatures = qq/SELECT `Feature`.`FeatName` , COUNT( * ) NB FROM `iLico_Log`, `Feature` WHERE `iLico_Log`.`Date` LIKE ? AND `iLico_Log`.`FeatID` = `Feature`.`FeatID` GROUP BY `Feature`.`FeatID` ORDER BY NB DESC LIMIT 10 /;

my $sth  = $dbh->prepare($TopFeatures) or die ("unable to prepare");
    $sth->execute($Date) ; 
    while( @record = $sth -> fetchrow_array())
       { 
     print $fh3 "$record[0]; $record[1];  \n";
       }

#other features number
my $Other = qq/SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `iLico_Log`.`FeatID`) NB FROM `iLico_Log`, `Feature` WHERE `iLico_Log`.`Date` LIKE ? AND `iLico_Log`.`FeatID` = `Feature`.`FeatID`/;
 $sth  = $dbh->prepare($Other) or die ("unable to prepare");
        $sth->execute($Date) ; 
        @record = $sth -> fetchrow_array();
     $other[0] = $record[0] - 10 ;
        print $fh3 "Other_features_number; @other \n";

#total usage of all and other features
my $TotalUsage =qq/SELECT COUNT( * ) SU  FROM `iLico_Log` , `Feature`  WHERE `iLico_Log`.`Date` LIKE ? AND `iLico_Log`.`FeatID` = `Feature`.`FeatID`/;
my $SUMTopFeatures = qq/select sum(NB) from (SELECT `Feature`.`FeatName` , COUNT( * ) NB FROM `iLico_Log`, `Feature` WHERE `iLico_Log`.`Date` LIKE ? AND `iLico_Log`.`FeatID` = `Feature`.`FeatID` GROUP BY `Feature`.`FeatID` ORDER BY NB DESC LIMIT 10) AS subquery /;

 $sth  = $dbh->prepare($TotalUsage) or die ("unable to prepare");
 my $sth1  = $dbh->prepare($SUMTopFeatures) or die ("unable to prepare");
    $sth->execute($Date) ;
    $sth1->execute($Date) ; 
    @record = $sth -> fetchrow_array();
    my @sum = $sth1 -> fetchrow_array();
     $other[0] = $record[0] - $sum[0] ;
        print $fh3 "Other_total_usage; @other"; 


#select login windows and groupe from file ldp_om.csv to be used in top_10_user and nomber Report/Groupe
while (<$fh5>) {
    chomp;
       my  ($mail, $uid, $site, $grp, $dvs, $cnt, $ccost, $mng, $typ, $phone, $first, $last, $login, $cn) = split ';', lc($_), 14;
     if (! exists $LOGIN_W{$login}) {
             $LOGIN_W{$login} = $grp;
        }

        if (! exists $hash{$login}) {
             $Groupe{$login} = $grp;
         $Nom_Complet{$login} = $cn;
     }
}

#top 10 user / Groups
my $TopUsers = qq/select ilicoUserLogin, COUNT(*) NB, Display from ilico_log I where Date like ? GROUP BY I.ilicoUserLogin ORDER BY NB DESC LIMIT 10/;
$sth  = $dbh->prepare($TopUsers) or die ("unable to prepare");
$sth->execute($Date) ; 
    while( @top_user = $sth -> fetchrow_array())
       { 
     $top_user[0] =~ s/\s+/ /g; 
         push (@array, lc($top_user[0]));
     my $login = lc($top_user[0]);
     $NUMBER{$login} = $top_user[1];
       }

foreach my $login ( @array ){ 
     $hash1{$login} = $Groupe{$login}; 
}

foreach my $login (sort {$NUMBER{$b} <=> $NUMBER{$a}} keys %hash1) { 
    my $grpe = uc($hash1{$login}) ;
    my $name = ucfirst($Nom_Complet{$login});
    print $fh4 "$name ; $NUMBER{$login} ; $grpe ; \n";
}

#Report/Groupe 
my $Groupe = qq/select ilicoUserLogin, Count(*) NB from ilico_log I where Date like ? GROUP BY I.ilicoUserLogin ORDER BY NB DESC  /;
$sth  = $dbh->prepare($Groupe) or die ("unable to prepare");
$sth->execute($Date) ;
while( @user = $sth -> fetchrow_array())
       { 
     $user[0] =~ s/\s+/ /g;
       my $login = lc($user[0]);
     $LOGIN_W{my $grp}{$login} = $user[1];
       }

foreach my $login ( keys %LOGIN_W) { 
    if (defined( $login ) and $login ne '')
    {
        $sum{$LOGIN_W{$login}} += $LOGIN_W{my $var}{$login} ;
    } 
}

for my $key (sort {$sum{$b} <=> $sum{$a}} keys %sum) {
    if ($sum{$key})
    {  
        my $KEYS = uc($key);
        print $fh6 "$KEYS; $sum{$key}; \n";
    }
}

close $fh1;
close $fh2;
close $fh3;
close $fh4;
close $fh5;
close $fh6;

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new ( 

            From        =>  'maha.mastouri@st.com',

            To          =>   'maha.mastouri@st.com', 

#       Cc      =>  'maha.mastouri@st.com',

            Subject     => "iLico Mertique $Month",

        Type        => 'text/plain' ,

            Path   =>  '/home/dev/text'

 ); 



 $msg->attach(  Type        =>  'TEXT',

                Path        =>  '/home/dev/NBgenerated_Reports.csv',

                Disposition =>  'attachment',
        Filename    =>   'NB_generated_Reports.csv'

 ); 

$msg->attach(  Type        =>  'TEXT',

                Path        =>  '/home/dev/Top_10_Features.csv',

                Disposition =>  'attachment',
        Filename    =>   'Top_10_Features.csv'

 ); 


$msg->attach(  Type        =>  'TEXT',

                Path        =>  '/home/dev/Report_Scope.csv',

                Disposition =>  'attachment',
        Filename    =>   'Report_Scope.csv'

 ); 

$msg->attach(  Type        =>  'TEXT',

                Path        =>  '/home/dev/Top_10_Users.csv',

                Disposition =>  'attachment',
        Filename    =>   'Top_10_Users.csv'

 ); 


$msg->attach(  Type        =>  'TEXT',

                Path        =>  '/home/dev/Report_Groupe.csv',

                Disposition =>  'attachment',
        Filename    =>   'Report_Groupe.csv'

 ); 

$msg->send();
```

Comment: What is failing? Show the code. /// For what reason? When `open` fails, it places the error reason in `$!`.

Comment: You may be opening the file with a relative path, and `cron` likely does a `chdir`.  Please show your code.

Comment: The message "not readable" does not look like something produce by the perl interpretor or by system (not in `man errno` nor in `perldoc perldiag`). I'm guessing it's a string in your program. Apparently you're program is checking the availability of file already. I suggest that when you're dealing with system calls, always include `$!` in your message output -- that usually indicase a reason.

Comment: The error message looks like maybe you have an unprintable character after `.csv`.  Do you by any chance use a Windows editor to wreck your files?

Answer (score 1):

cron context is very different than a login shell. It has no env vars by default. It appears to me that your program depends on `$ENV{USER}` to build it's output (or input). Well, that env var is just going to be missing from  cron. crontabs are executed by "cron" daemon and not as your login shell.

You can try to print the whole `%ENV` to somewhere like "/tmp/env.txt" just to see that it's basically an empty hash. It's the best if you can change the program not to depend on env var. You may also try to add them back right before the schedule line:

```
USER=dev
/3 * * * * /home/dev/metrique.pl &> /home/dev/output.txt
```

I must also notify you that after doing this, the env var USER becomes present for all the schedules below these 2 lines. Those env vars can also be inspected by `ps e`.

If an env var is required just to decide an input path, than it's as easy as getting the input path from `@ARGV`

Comment: You cannot portably use `&>` in `cron`.  The correct, portable expression is `/home/dev/metrique.pl >/home/dev/output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @tripleee , i tried with  /home/dev/metrique.pl > /home/dev/output.txt 2>&1.  But still the same error .

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is the only problem, out your question is too sprawly. Try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It should  run your `.profile(or .bash_profile` for bash)  before executing the commands from cron.So, put it before your command in cron as shown. Similarly if there are any profile scripts which you run on login that is used in the perl script, those have to be included.

```
/3 * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /home/dev/metrique.pl &> /home/dev/output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, crontab execute the script in the home "/home/httpldev/" (default), so I changed the execution path by following;

0 9 1 * * cd /home/httpldev/iLicoMetrics/ && /home/httpldev/iLicoMetrics/metrique.pl &> /dev/null .

Thank you a lot for your help.